# Python list slicing 0:-1 leaving out last item

Tags: python, list, slice

I am trying to slice a list on certain conditions and if the condition is `False` I want to return the full list by only changing the `[x:y]` values.

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

if condition == True:
    y = 3
    x = 0
else:
    y = I_dont_know
    x = I_dont_know
return list[x:y]
```

Below is the current method I am trying to use but as you can see it is removing the last item of the list

```
>>> list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> len(list)
6
>>> len(list[0:-1])
5
>>> list[0:-1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

how do I stop the last item from getting sliced off and/or is there a better method?

Comment: Unrelated, but it's probably best not to name your list `list`, because that's a builtin.

Comment: "how do I stop the last item from getting sliced off" The (simplest) necessary value for the stopping point is `None` (or if you write the slice directly, you can just omit it). Please see the linked duplicate to understand why. Alternately, instead of trying to choose where to slice conditionally, you can just... conditionally either slice or not slice the list.

Comment: Upper boundaries in slices are *exclusive*, so `my_list[0:-1]` means "everything except the last element". You can do `my_list`, `my_list[:]`, `my_list[0:]`, `my_list[0:len(my_list)]` or even `my_list[0:None]` as Karl Knechtel noted.

Comment: list[0:-1] here means the last iteration before -1. So, if you want to get all iteration use list[0:]